# Amazon Linux cannot access nginx on port 80

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have installed `nginx` on my AMI by `yum`

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

And then, I open all port in my AMI `security group`

`All traffic - All - All - 0.0.0.0/0`

And then, I start `nginx` by command

```
sudo service nginx start
```

And then, I access my `nginx` web service by `http://public-ip`
but I cannot access by this way.

I try to check the connection in my server.

```
ssh my_account@my_ip
```

And then,

```
wget http://localhost -O-
```

And It worked fine.

I cannot figure out what is the root cause, and then I change `nginx` port from `80` to `8081` and I restart the `nginx` server.

And then, I try to access again. It worked fine. WTH...

```
http://public-ip:8081
```

I don't know exactly what is going on?

Could you tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Check your VPC security-group settings.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: ... What kind of settings should I check?

Comment: In short, if your EC2 instance is in a VPC, then you need to check the VPC security group also. VPC configuration is in the Networking section of the main console. This question is more suitable for ServerFault, so you should get a better response there.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was? I currently have the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possibilities:

- You are blocking the connections with a firewall on the host.
- Security Group rules disallow this access
- You are in a VPC and have not set up an Internet Gateway or route to host
- Your Nginx configurations are set to explicitly listen on host and port combinations such that it responds to "localhost" but not to the public IP or host name. You could post your Nginx configs and be more specific about how it doesn't work when you try remotely. It is timing out? Not resolving? Receiving an HTTP response but not what you expected?